# Iterate through series of timers

Tags: javascript, timer, iteration

I wrote a short program for my exercise routine. It takes a JSON array of exercise names and duration (seconds) and puts it on the screen. The JSON looks like this:

```
var exerciseArray = [
    {
        "desc":       "Pushup/Pullup",
        "countdown":  30
    }, {
        "desc":       "Squat punch",
        "countdown":  45
    }, {
        "desc":       "Jumping jacks",
        "countdown":  60
    }
];
```

The function works, but it seems to be to be kind of a kludge. My problem was that I couldn't figure out how work with `setInterval` to iterate through the list of exercises (`exerciseArray`). What I did in the end is just decrement the `countdown` value, and when it's zero, move to the next item in `exerciseArray` (`i++;`). When I hit the end of the array — as measured by `i` and `exerciseArray.length` — I just run `clearInterval` and I'm done. Code below (I removed some of the extraneous stuff that just updates the HTML with the number of seconds, you can see the full thing on [github](http://github.com/eykanal/exerciseTimer)):

```
function exerciseTimer(exerciseArray) {
    var i = 0;
    var exerciseObject = exerciseArray[i];
    // do stuff
    var tt = setInterval(function() {
        var exerciseObject = exerciseArray[i];
        // write html to the page
        exerciseObject.countdown = exerciseObject.countdown - 1;
        if (exerciseObject.countdown <= 0) { 
            if(i < (exerciseArray.length - 1)) {
                i++;
            } else {
                clearInterval(tt);
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

My question is, what is the appropriate way to iterate while using `setInterval`? Is there a cleaner way? This feels very ugly to me.

Comment: Is your intent to have the code write some HTML, wait until that exercise timeout, and then write some different HTML and then wait for the next timeout, or are you doing updates or executing other code **during** the period of each exercise?

Comment: @Edward - There are updates during the exercise; namely, the timer counts down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need the entries once, you could simply keep using `shift` until there are no more entries:

```
var exercises = [
    {
        "desc":       "Pushup/Pullup",
        "countdown":  30
    }, {
        "desc":       "Squat punch",
        "countdown":  45
    }, {
        "desc":       "Jumping jacks",
        "countdown":  60
    }
];

function exerciseTimer(exercises) {
    // do stuff
    var exercise = exercises.shift(),
        tt = setInterval(function() {
            // write html to the page
            exercise.countdown = exercise.countdown - 1;
            //Does it work ?
            console.log( exercise );
            if (exercise.countdown <= 0) { 
                exercise = exercises.shift(); 
                if(!exercise) {
                    clearInterval(tt);
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    };

exerciseTimer( exercises );
```

I would also suggest to not make the type of the variable part of the variable name. `exercise` and `exercises` are much easier to read than `exerciseArray` and `exerciseObject`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that what you want is to iterate through each exercise, display something static and wait for the timeout to expire before moving on to the next, I might do it like this:

```
<h1 id="exercisename">Get Ready</h1>
<h2 id="seconds">0</h2>
<p>Click the button to start the exercises.</p>
<button onclick="nextExercise()">Begin</button>  
<script>
var exercises = [
    {
        "desc":       "Pushup/Pullup",
        "countdown":  3
    }, {
        "desc":       "Squat punch",
        "countdown":  4
    }, {
        "desc":       "Jumping jacks",
        "countdown":  6
    }
];
var excount = 0;
var timeleft = 0;
var secondsTimer;
function setSeconds(s)
{
    var sec = document.getElementById('seconds');
    sec.textContent = timeleft;
}
function tick()
{
    setSeconds(timeleft--);
    if (timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(secondsTimer);
    }
}
function nextExercise()
{
    var ex = exercises[excount++];
    var name = document.getElementById('exercisename');
    if (typeof ex == 'undefined') {
        name.textContent = "Done";
        excount = 0;
    } else {
        name.textContent = ex.desc+" for "+ex.countdown+" seconds";
        timeleft = ex.countdown;
        setSeconds(timeleft);
        secondsTimer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
        setTimeout(nextExercise,ex.countdown*1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Obviously for a real workout, you'd probably want to increase the times a bit. :)

### Update:

Based on a comment, I've also added a countdown timer.  Note that the countdown is handled as using `setInterval` while the exercise timers use a separate and independent `setTimeout`.

Comment: The way this works now, I have it counting down for me. I use the `setIterator` to change the displayed second as time progresses. This is a minor decrease in functionality.